# Apache Solr nGram grouping issue

Tags: solr

i got issue when i am grouping my ngrams. my query is

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/archiveCore/select?group.field=strSO&group=true&q=strSO%3A*&rows=2147483647&start=0&wt=json&indent=true&fl=strSO
```

it shows correct results to me at web browser(chrome) like

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":51,
    "params":{
      "q":"strSO:*",
      "indent":"true",
      "fl":"strSO",
      "start":"0",
      "rows":"2147483647",
      "wt":"json",
      "group.field":"strSO",
      "group":"true"}},
  "grouped":{
    "strSO":{
      "matches":112559,
      "groups":[{
          "groupValue":"EV11777-01",
          "doclist":{"numFound":53,"start":0,"docs":[
              {
                "strSO":"EV11777-01"}]
          }},
        {
          "groupValue":"EV15872-01",
          "doclist":{"numFound":1829,"start":0,"docs":[
              {
                "strSO":"EV15872-01"}]
          }},
        {
          "groupValue":"EV16143-02",
          "doclist":{"numFound":929,"start":0,"docs":[
              {
                "strSO":"EV16143-02"}]
          }},
        {
          "groupValue":"E896759-01",
          "doclist":{"numFound":888,"start":0,"docs":[
              {
                "strSO":"E896759-01"}]
          }},
        {
          "groupValue":"E893257-02",
          "doclist":{"numFound":1250,"start":0,"docs":[
              {
                "strSO":"E893257-02"}]
          }},
        {
          "groupValue":"EV16232-02",
          "doclist":{"numFound":999,"start":0,"docs":[
              {
                "strSO":"EV16232-02"}]
          }},
        {
          "groupValue":"EV12473-01",
          "doclist":{"numFound":1545,"start":0,"docs":[
              {
                "strSO":"EV12473-01"}]
          }},
        {
          "groupValue":"E896479-01",
          "doclist":{"numFound":1016,"start":0,"docs":[
              {
                "strSO":"E896479-01"}]
          }},
        {
          "groupValue":"EV12455-02",
          "doclist":{"numFound":1299,"start":0,"docs":[
              {
                "strSO":"EV12455-02"}]
          }},
        {
          "groupValue":"EV12459-02",
          "doclist":{"numFound":1250,"start":0,"docs":[
              {
                "strSO":"EV12459-02"}]
          }},
        {
          "groupValue":"E876243-01",
          "doclist":{"numFound":1238,"start":0,"docs":[
              {
                "strSO":"E876243-01"}]
          }},
        {
          "groupValue":"E874707-02",
          "doclist":{"numFound":1116,"start":0,"docs":[
              {
                "strSO":"E874707-02"}]
          }},
        {
          "groupValue":"EV12648-02",
          "doclist":{"numFound":1025,"start":0,"docs":[
              {
                "strSO":"EV12648-02"}]
```

but it doesnt work in java. i am putting the query in my projects jquery and ngram shows nothing. i dont understand why it shows me nothing. its working well at web browser.

here is my schema.xml to configurate ngrams

```
<fieldType name="text_ngram" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" stored="false" multiValued="true">
<analyzer type="index">
<tokenizer class="solr.NGramTokenizerFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="20"/>    
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
<analyzer type="query">
<tokenizer class="solr.EdgeNGramTokenizerFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="20"/>
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Anybody can help me to fix this??

here is my jquery codes

```
<script>
$(function() {
var URL_PREFIX = "http://localhost:8983/solr/archiveCore/select?q=strSO:*";
var URL_SUFFIX = "&group.field=strSO&group=true&rows=2147483647&start=0&wt=json&indent=true&fl=strSO";
$("#searchBoxstrSO").autocomplete({
source : function(request, response) {
var URL = URL_PREFIX + $("#searchBoxstrSO").val() + URL_SUFFIX;
$.ajax({
url : URL,
success : function(data) {
var docs = JSON.stringify(data.response.docs);
var jsonData = JSON.parse(docs);
response($.map(jsonData, function(value, key) {
return {
label : value.strSO
}
}));
},
dataType : 'jsonp',
jsonp : 'json.wrf'
});
},
minLength : 1
})
});
$(function() {
var URL_PREFIX = "http://localhost:8983/solr/archiveCore/select?q=strSO:";
var URL_MIDDLE = "OR strSO_ngram:";
var URL_SUFFIX = "&group.field=strSO&group=true&rows=2147483647&start=0&wt=json&indent=true&fl=strSO";
$("#ngramBoxstrSO").autocomplete(
{
source : function(request, response) {
var searchString = "\"" + $("#ngramBoxstrSO").val() + "\"";
var URL = URL_PREFIX + searchString + URL_MIDDLE
+ searchString + URL_SUFFIX;
$.ajax({
url : URL,
success : function(data) {
var docs = JSON.stringify(data.response.docs);
var jsonData = JSON.parse(docs);
response($.map(jsonData, function(value, key) {
return {
label : value.strSO
}
}));
},
dataType : 'jsonp',
jsonp : 'json.wrf'
});
},
minLength : 1
})
});
</script>
```

Comment: Are your jQuery request even allowed to contact your Solr server? Usually cross site requests will fail when they're not made against the same host that served the original HTML.

Comment: The request contacting my Solr server. if my solr query be like this **http://localhost:8983/solr/archiveCore/select?q=strSO:&wt=json** the ngram shows me the results but results are multivalued. i want to distinct them like in SQL